# Dynamic Linq Library Help

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I have the following class:

```
public class Item
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and a list of it:

```
List<Item> items;
```

I need to filter and order this list dynamically using SQL-Like strings. The catch is, that I need to order it by the Data dictionary.

For example: `Order By Data["lastname"]` or `Where Data["Name"].StartsWith("a")`. I thought to use the dynamic linq library, but is there any way that my clients can write without the Data[]? For example:

```
Name.StartsWith("abc")
```

instead of

```
Data["Name"].StartsWith("abc")
```

?

Comment: Hm ... an extension class might be of help ... the idea is that you hide the real implementation and provide an easier proxy. Name would have to be a class that is aware of Data.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data
    { get; set; }

    public string Name { get { return Data["lastname"]; } }
}
//Call by: i.Name.StartsWith("abc");
```

Or an extension method:

```
public static class ItemExtensions 
{
  public static string Name(this Item item)
  {
    return item.Data["lastname"];
  }
}
//Call by: i.Name().StartsWith("abc");
```

Or if it's a **very** commonly used method, you could add something like a `.NameStartsWith()`:

```
public static string NameStartsWith(this Item item, stirng start)
{
  return item.Data["lastname"].StartsWith(start);
}
//Call by: i.NameStartsWith("abc");
```

Comment: No, I can't. And that's the reason I asked this question

Comment: @Alon - These are 3 distinct options, the last 2 do not rely on adding the property in the first option.  Other than dynamic in 4.0 or reflection, there's no non-index way to do this, which is what you asked :)

Comment: "No, I can't."? Like Nick said, these are 3 effective options that C# will allow you to use in the scenario you've described. If they won't work for some reason perhaps you should provide some more context as to why.

Comment: I can't, because I get this dynamic data from a database. and I don't want to change my c# classes everytime I change something in the database. :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with the Linq Dynamic Query unit.  That unit is for when you have *actual* fields/properties and the names of them will be given to you at runtime.  In other words, you have a class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to be able to write a query like this:

```
var sortedPeople = people.OrderBy("FirstName");
```

You are trying to do **the exact opposite of this** - you have a class that does not have any actual properties, just an attribute dictionary, and you want compile-time safety.  You can't have it; there's no way to guarantee that an item will be in the dictionary, *especially* when the dictionary is public and anyone can add/remove directly from it!

If there's some reason that you *must* use that specific class design, then you could conceivably write some wrappers as Nick has presented, but I wouldn't even bother - they're not actually providing any encapsulation because the `Data` dictionary is still wide open to the whole world.  Instead, I would just provide a single *safe* getter method or indexer property and create a few constants (or an enum) with the names of properties you expect to be in there.

```
public class Item
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

    public string GetValue(string key)
    {
        if (Data == null)
            return null;
        string result;
        Data.TryGetValue(key, out result);
        return result;
    }
}

public class ItemKeys
{
    public const string Name = "Name";
    public const string Foo = "Foo";
}
```

And so on.  Really the `ItemKeys` isn't that important, the safe `GetValue` method is what's important, because otherwise you run the risk of a `NullReferenceException` if `Data` hasn't been assigned, or a `KeyNotFoundException` if **even one `Item`** instance doesn't have that property.  Using the `GetValue` method here will succeed no matter what:

```
var myItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.GetValue(ItemKeys.Name));
```

If you find you're writing a lot of repetitive code for the same attributes, *then* start worrying about adding shortcut properties or extension methods to the class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't know the names of the properties at compile-time (in which case, you could simply define properties and wouldn't have this problem). I have two suggestions that you could try, but I didn't implement any of them myself, so I can't guarantee that it will work.

- If you can use .NET 4.0, you could inherit from `DynamicObject` and implement `TryGetMember` method (which is called when you use `o.Foo` on an object that is declared as `dynamic`). Assuming that Dynamic LINQ works with DLR, it should automatically invoke this method for objects that inherit from `DynamicObject`. Inside the `TryGetMember` method, you would get a name of the accessed property, so you could perform a dictionary lookup. (However, this solution would work only if Dynamic LINQ integrates well with DLR).
- In any case, you could do some basic parsing of the string entered by the user and replace for example `Name` with `Data["Name"]`. This would definitely work, but it may be a bit difficult (because you should probably at least check that you're doing the replace in correct context - e.g. not inside a string constant).

Regarding extension methods - I'm not sure if Dynamic LINQ handles extension methods (but, I don't think so, because that would require searching all referenced assemblies)